# Is there a way to modify the request body during PACT verification?

Tags: pact

I am trying to run a PACT test on the provider side and I don't know how to manipulate the request body that I get from the Pact file. I need to do this because I have to use an id from State step.

In my case, I need to perform a request in State step and afterwards to use the response of that request in the actual Pact verification test. So, I would like to replace a value from the pact file with the one obtained in the State.

Also, for being even more complicated, my body is an XML. So here it is how my pact request looks like:

```
"request": {
   "method": "POST",
   "path": "/path/url",             
   "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/xml"
   },
   "body": "<note> <to>John</to> <from>Jane</from> <subject>Reminder</subject> </note>"
}
```

As I said, in the Provider State I will have a request and the response of this will be let's say 'Mary'. So my question would be how can I replace 'Jane' with 'Mary' in the Pact request body when executing the verification test? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve my problem, modifying the request in TargetRequestFilter.

```
@TargetRequestFilter
public void updateRequest(HttpPost request) {
    HttpEntity entity = request.getEntity();
    String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    body = replace(body, "Jane", "Mary");
    entity = new StringEntity(body);
    request.setEntity(entity);
}
```

This piece of code will modify the request right before making the call and will send the desired value instead the one that we have in the Pact file.